# datatemplate in place of hierarchialdatatemplate to avoid hierarchy for a particular group

Tags: c#, wpf

```
Group1
   Item1
   Item2
NullGroupItem1
NullGroupItem2
```

As shown in the structure above, I am trying to use a datatemplate in place of hierarchialdatatemplate in order to avoid the hierarchy in the treelist for a particular group to show nullgroupitems. The issue is that the itemscontrol in the datatemplate behaves like a single item rather than individual treeviewitems.

Please suggest.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via `ItemTemplateSelector`. You can define two templates one will be  `HierarichalDataTemplate` and other will be `DataTemplate`:

In `SelectTemplate()` method of your `ItemTemplateSelector`, you can check if you want to return `HierarchicalDataTemplate` or `DataTemplate` for your Group

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector " MyHierarchicalTemplate={StaticResource YOURHIERARCHICALTEMPLATE} MyDataTemplate={StaticResource YOURDATATEMPLATEFORNULLGROUP}/>

<TreeView ItemTemplateSelector={StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}/>


public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MyDataTemplate{get;set;}
    public HierarchicalDataTemplate MyHierarchicalTemplate{get;set;}
    public override DataTemplate 
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //Check for null group
        if(NullGroup)
           return MyDataTemplate;

        return MyHierarchicalTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue is not with template selection. For that particular group, the items are presented as a single treeviewitem.

Comment: sorry i didnt get it... you want to show the nullgroupitems as seperate items with no children right?

Comment: so the approach i suggested will resolve this issue... each nullgroupitem will be seperate...not part of single treeviewitem

Comment: Perhaps if you could show me how MyDataTemplate looks in xaml, my issue could get resolved. Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the MyDataTemplate definition in xaml.

Comment: Template you want to set as MyDataTemplate can be a simple template containing the label or textblock: `<DataTemplate x:Key="NullDataTemplate"><TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/></DataTemplate>` and then you can set this template as MyDataTemplate of TemplateSelector `<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector " MyHierarchicalTemplate={StaticResource YOURHIERARCHICALTEMPLATE} MyDataTemplate={StaticResource NullDataTemplate}/>`

Comment: Thank you for your message. If I do it this way, it shows the group but doesn't show the items in it. In order to show the items inside, I used ItemsControl but all the items act as a single treeviewitem instead.

Comment: but you dont have items in null group right? for group with items in it you have hierarchical template

Comment: Yes, I do have items in the null group and I would like them to be shown as a flat list hence I opted for a datatemplate in place of a hierarchical data template. In that datatemplate I used itemscontrol and all the items are behaving like a single treeviewitem. That is the issue..